# How to configure Spring Webflow 2.3.1 with @Configuration?

Tags: java, spring, configuration, annotations, spring-webflow

Typically, the Spring webflow configuration is imported from `application-context.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans .../>

    ....

    <import resource="config/webflow-config.xml" />

</beans>
```

But in spring 3.1, it is possible to perform all configuration from Java with `@Configuration` and get rid of `application-context.xml`.

I have the following for my web configuration:

```
@Configuration
@Import({ MyConfig1.class, MyConfig2.class })
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    ...

}
```

Is it possible to get rid of `webflow-config.xml` too using `@Configuration`? If yes how? If no, how to get my web configuration to include `webflow-config.xml`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The latest Spring Webflow does not support defining flows through `@Configuration`, you will have to define the flows as XML and import it into a `@Configuration` file.

You can use @ImportResource to import a webflow.xml file into a @Configuration File:

```
@ImportResource("/WEB-INF/web/webflow.xml")
```